# Setting a minimum date on a jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to create a DatePicker out of a textbox using jQuery. I have the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtServiceDateRequested").datepicker({
        showAnim: "puff", 
        minDate: new Date(2013,10,23)
    }); 
});
```

I am trying to make it so that dates prior to 10/23/2013 can not be selected. Using this code though, for some reason, its disabling all days prior to 11/23/2013 (November instead of October). Does anyone have any thoughts? Am I using the `minDate` property wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Months in JavaScript are zero based, so January is zero, February is one, etc. So October is actually 9, not 10.

Use `minDate: new Date(2013,9,23)`

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

> month: Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for
>   January to 11 for December.

Comment: Usually, I use new Date(2013,10-1,23) just to remember that fact. I don't think I'm the only one.

Comment: Duh and I actually knew this. But for some reason, the fact that javascript uses 0-based months escaped me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you configure `minDate` with a `Date`, then @j08691 is exactly right. Months are 0-based. That's a JavaScript thing rather than a Datepicker thing.

Still as the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) shows, you can use a string too if it is formatted properly (according to the `dateFormat` option). That could help you get it right too in a more intuitive way.